# Quantlib: How do I price a ZC bond using the Hull White model?

Tags: programming, quantlib, hullwhite, quants

I am trying to use QuantLib to model short rate and looks like QL has some material here
http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/hull-white-simulation-quantlib-python.html

I have been able to simulate using the actual term structure, although in the attached link for simplicity GB has assumed flat forwards. Which is what I have used below.

I am calculating the price of the zero coupon bond at a time t using the below code

```
def price(T, t, r0):
    tau = T - t
    B = (1 - np.exp(-a * tau)) / a
    A = np.exp(-r0 * tau - B * r0 - sigma ** 2 / (4 * a ** 3) *
               (np.exp(-a * T) - np.exp(-a * t)) * (np.exp(2 * a * t) - 1))
    return A * np.exp(-r0 * B)
```

but I feel my zc bond prices are all over the place. Any clues what an I doing wrong here?

Does QuantLib provide a wrapper to calculate the zc prices using the HW model by any chance?

The complete code is below

````
import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


sigma = 0.1
a = 0.1
length = 30 # in years
steps_per_year = 12
timestep = length * steps_per_year
forward_rate = 0.05
day_count = ql.Thirty360()
todays_date = ql.Date(15, 1, 2015)


ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todays_date

spot_curve = ql.FlatForward(todays_date, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(forward_rate)), day_count)
spot_curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(spot_curve)

hw_process = ql.HullWhiteProcess(spot_curve_handle, a, sigma)
rng = ql.GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator(ql.UniformRandomSequenceGenerator(timestep, ql.UniformRandomGenerator()))
seq = ql.GaussianPathGenerator(hw_process, length, timestep, rng, False)


def generate_paths(n_scenarios):
    arr = np.zeros((n_scenarios, timestep+1))
    for i in range(n_scenarios):
        sample_path = seq.next()
        path = sample_path.value()
        time = [path.time(j) for j in range(len(path))]
        value = [path[j] for j in range(len(path))]
        arr[i, :] = np.array(value)
    return np.array(time), arr

n_scenarios = 1
time, paths = generate_paths(n_scenarios)
rates = pd.DataFrame(paths).T



#price a zero coupon bond

n_years = length
num_steps = timestep
dt = 1 / steps_per_year
prices = np.empty_like(rates)


def price(T, t, r0):
    tau = T - t
    B = (1 - np.exp(-a * tau)) / a
    A = np.exp(-r0 * tau - B * r0 - sigma ** 2 / (4 * a ** 3) *
               (np.exp(-a * T) - np.exp(-a * t)) * (np.exp(2 * a * t) - 1))
    return A * np.exp(-r0 * B)

prices[0] = price(n_years,dt*0,rates.values[0])

for steps in range(1,num_steps+1):
    prices[steps] = price(n_years, dt * steps, rates.values[steps])

plt.plot(prices)
plt.show()

```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the price in HW[4] for a ZCB at time $t$:

\begin{align}
P(t,T) &= A(t,T) e^{-B(t,T) r(t)}\\
A(t,T) &= {\frac {P(0,T)} {P(0,t)}} \exp \Bigl( B(t,T)F(0,t) - {\frac {\sigma^2} {4a}} B(t,T)^2(1-e^{-2at})\Bigr)\\
B(t,T) &= {\frac {1-e^{-a(T-t)}} {a}}
\end{align}

You seem to be simulating to rate $r(t)$ at time $t$ and putting that into your function argument `r0`. I'm not exactly sure what `r0` is supposed to be, but note that the equations above include $F(0,t)$ - which is just a constant in your simulation (as you've used a `FlatForward` curve which I think should replace most of your `r0` terms, but the final line should read `return A * np.exp(-rt * B)`, where `rt` is the current value of rate. There is also a sign error on the `B * r0` term, which should be `+` instead of `-`

When I make these changes (and slightly reduce the rates vol, as 10% for 30Y is a long time and a lot of vol for a short rates model), and average the prices along the paths, I see the following, which nicely shows the bond's pull-to-par as its maturity approaches:

[image: ZCB price paths in HW]

Full modified code:

```
import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


sigma = 0.01
a = 0.1
length = 30 # in years
steps_per_year = 12
timestep = length * steps_per_year
forward_rate = 0.01
day_count = ql.Thirty360()
todays_date = ql.Date(15, 1, 2015)


ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todays_date

spot_curve = ql.FlatForward(todays_date, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(forward_rate)), day_count)
spot_curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(spot_curve)

hw_process = ql.HullWhiteProcess(spot_curve_handle, a, sigma)
rng = ql.GaussianRandomSequenceGenerator(ql.UniformRandomSequenceGenerator(timestep, ql.UniformRandomGenerator()))
seq = ql.GaussianPathGenerator(hw_process, length, timestep, rng, False)


def generate_paths(n_scenarios):
    arr = np.zeros((n_scenarios, timestep+1))
    for i in range(n_scenarios):
        sample_path = seq.next()
        path = sample_path.value()
        time = [path.time(j) for j in range(len(path))]
        value = [path[j] for j in range(len(path))]
        arr[i, :] = np.array(value)
    return np.array(time), arr

n_scenarios = 1000
time, paths = generate_paths(n_scenarios)
rates = pd.DataFrame(paths).T

#price a zero coupon bond
n_years = length
num_steps = timestep
dt = 1 / steps_per_year
prices = np.empty_like(rates)


def price(T, t, f0, rt):
    tau = T - t
    B = (1 - np.exp(-a * tau)) / a
    A = np.exp(-f0 * tau + B * f0 - sigma ** 2 / (4 * a ** 3) *
               (np.exp(-a * T) - np.exp(-a * t)) * (np.exp(2 * a * t) - 1))
    return A * np.exp(-rt * B)

prices[0] = price(n_years,dt*0, forward_rate, rates.values[0])

for steps in range(1,num_steps+1):
    prices[steps] = price(n_years, dt * steps, forward_rate, rates.values[steps])


fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.title("All ZCB paths")
plt.plot(prices)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)

ave = [np.mean(x) for x in prices]
plt.plot(ave)
plt.title("Average ZCB paths")

plt.show()
```

[4]: Hull, J., White, A., “Pricing Interest-Rate-Derivative Securities”, Review of Financial Studies, Volume 3, Issue 4, pp. 573-592, 1990

Comment: thanks @StackG, that was really helpful.

Comment: thanks again, this was really helpful. The equation makes sense now, although had a question and excuse my ignorance as I haven't dabbled with this before. but instead of defining a constant forward rate I pass the actually current term structure, whats the most efficent way to get F(0,t), I believe its instantaneous fwd rate as seen at time 0 betw t and T?

Comment: $F(0,t)$ is the initial rate from $0$ to $t$, you can get it from the `ql.YieldTermStructureHandle` object (here, you've assumed it is constant). It doesn't depend on the ZCB's maturity time $T$

Comment: thanks again man!

Comment: looks like F(0,t) has been a struggle. Assuming that I get the current term structure from here ```https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/quantlib-how-do-i-price-a-bond-after-having-built-a-term-structure/55997?noredirect=1#comment80321_55997```. So my spot_curve_handle in the above code will change to ```spot_curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(yieldcurve)```. now, how do I get new F(0,t) for each num_steps? Appreciate your help again.